# Error in first line of [code] section

Tags: inno-setup

I've been working on an Inno script for several days now, adding a few lines at a time. When I now try to run my script I get the error:

"Variable Expected"

in the first character of my [code] section:

```
[Code]
function SetFocus(hWnd: HWND): HWND; external 'SetFocus@user32.dll stdcall';
```

How can I track down where the problem is?

Comment: This import is correct. Compiler reports the exact place where it fails with line and column and if you're not including any external files in your script (through the `#include` directive), you will find this place right in the script editor. Are you including any files with the `#include` directive ?

Comment: It says Line 214 Col 1 which is the "f" of "function" on this line. There are no #include directives in the script. I'm baffled.

Comment: I found the problem was actually in a line of code some 400 lines after this one where I was mistakenly trying to assign StringChangeEx to a string variable rather than an integer. It seems strange though that it didn't highlight that line as containing an error instead of the first line of code.

Comment: Without knowing your script we can only guess. Still, you can always take the code that you think it's not compilable and try to compile it in a plain new script. Now thinking about it, didn't you use more than one `[Code]` section ?

Comment: Were you using the built-in Inno editor or were you using a third-party editor?  Because that can make a difference.